# In the D language, how do you perform a binary search on an array of structs?

Tags: arrays, binary-search, d

E.g., if you have a sorted array of the struct:

```
struct Item
{
    int val;
    string property;
}
```

How would you go about using these with `assumeSorted` so that you could then search on `Item.val`?

All the examples of ranges I can find online use arrays of integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define a comparison operator: http://dlang.org/operatoroverloading.html#compare

```
struct Item
{
    int val;
    string property;

    int opCmp(ref const Item other) const
    {
        return val - other.val;
    }
}
```

After the comparison operator is defined, all sorting-related functions should work just like with integers.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that as structs are value types, opCmp should be defined as `int opCmp(ref const S s) const { ... }` as suggested in your link.